# Exibir player na área de notificações do Android

Tags: javascript, android, apache-cordova

Criei um aplicativo que transmite uma *Streaming* da rádio, porem se eu "minimizar" o aplicativo ele continua tocando.

Então eu gostaria de saber como posso fazer para que abra uma box na *lista de notificações* do Android, tipo o aplicativo **Play Música**

[image]

Só que acredito que a verdadeira e maior diferença entre os aplicativos é que o meu da rádio é feito pelo **Phonegap** que se resume a **HTML5** ao invés de java puro.

[image]

Comment: Sugiro fortemente que você leia: [Quando se deve colocar o nome da linguagem no título?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297)

Comment: Editei a pergunta, pois o problema e totalmente orientado ao phonegap e deve-se evitar usar tags irrelevantes, outra coisa retirei o link pois nao ajuda em nada com a duvida. Uma duvida Pedro, voce quer colocar o player aonde fica as notificacoes? Porque se for isto, entao pushs nao parecem fazer parte do problema (apesar de ficar no mesmo local), poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Guilherme Nascimento, queria simplesmente que quando a pessoa minimizar o APP da rádio apareça uma cixa como a do Play Música só que somente com o botao de pausa e play e o ícone da radio?.. Sacas??

Comment: Por isto perguntei, o titulo fala sobre pushs, mas você da a entender que quer criar um Widget na lista de notificações. Ou seja a unica coisa que lhe perguntei amigo é "o que notificações tem haver com o problema", não perguntei por mal é que eu queria tentar melhorar o titulo da tua pergunta pra que mais pessoas possam se interessar e tentar responder a tua duvida :)

Comment: Resolveu seu problema?

Comment: De uma olhada neste exemplo no GitHub. Nele, possui o que você busca. https://github.com/iammert/RadioPlayerService

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o [Cordova Music Controls Plugin](https://github.com/homerours/cordova-music-controls-plugin)

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/homerours/cordova-music-controls-plugin
```

É muito fácil de fazer a integração dele com seu app.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode montar uma notificação personalizada, podendo acrescentar mais informações uteis para o usuário.
Ao montar sua notificação, caso deseje colocar seu proprio layout (e com isso mais informações pro usuario) precisaria adicionar a função "Builder.setStyle()".

Um exemplo seria assim:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("Event tracker")
    .setContentText("Events received")
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
        new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
String[] events = new String[6];
// Sets a title for the Inbox in expanded layout
inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Event tracker details:");
...
// Moves events into the expanded layout
for (int i=0; i < events.length; i++) {

    inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
}
// Moves the expanded layout object into the notification object.
mBuilder.setStyle(inBoxStyle);
...
// Issue the notification here.
```

A Google possui uma boa documentação para isso:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html?hl=pt-br

Comment: Talvez este link seja uma boa dica, mas para uma resposta, seria importante transcrever as partes mais relevantes para que o essencial possa ser lido aqui no site mesmo. Dois links que podem ajudar a aproveitar melhor o SOpt: [Tour], [Answer] .

Comment: seria mais legal ainda ajudar com resposta que tenham haver com a duvida colocada, CITO 0 original "....maior diferença entre os aplicativos é que o meu da rádio é feito pelo Phonegap que se resume a HTML5 ao invés de java puro.",   sempre me parecceu que se manter dentro do topico eh importante @Bacco.

Comment: Olá, @CamilaYamamoto, note que meu comentário havia sido feito antes da edição do autor: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/150911/revisions - Nos casos em que entender que o post não é resposta, lembre-se de usar as sinalizações do site (link "sinalizar", logo abaixo da postagem).

Comment: Entendi, voce esta muito correto. Mas nao percebi qualquer orienteacao para o @Nimai Marchiori com relacao a ele tratar de android , quando a duvida eh derecionada para cordova... ou ele esta bem colocado dentro do assunto?  Veja, pergunto porque gostaria de saber mais da politica do SO.